# update query with multiple inner joins

Tags: c#, sql

I want to update the table with multiple inner join query but when I write the query it through an error incorrect syntax near inner keyword

```
     Update inventory_detail INNER JOIN inventory 
    ON inventory_detail.inventory_id = Inventory.Inventory_id 
    INNER JOIN Ingredients 
    ON Inventory.Inventory_id=Ingredients.invenotry_id 
         SET inventory_detail.Quantity=inventory_detail.Quantity-1 
        WHERE inventory_detail.loc_id =1 AND Ingredients.item_id=27 ;
```

[ERD diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBrFc.png)

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? [edit[ your question with that tag.  Also you tagged it with c#, but there is no c# code shown, only SQL

Comment: its because i am using local B of c# (sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
UPDATE inventory_detail
SET Quantity = Quantity - 1
FROM inventory_detail
    INNER JOIN inventory
        ON inventory_detail.inventory_id = Inventory.Inventory_id
    INNER JOIN Ingredients
        ON Inventory.Inventory_id = Ingredients.invenotry_id
WHERE inventory_detail.loc_id = 1
      AND Ingredients.item_id = 27;
```